# SEGV issue while running .NET Application using mono framework

Tags: .net, linux, mono, window

I have created one .NET Binary which is working fine in windows without any issue.

I also want to run that application on Linux Platform using mono framework  which is used to run as well as develop the same GUI related application as we are doing in windows.

I have installed mono 2.10.8.1 in my Linux PC and run that application which is working fine without any issue at staring point.

But whenever i ran that application for sometime around 15 minutes by performing some GUI related operation then at that time GUI Application goes into hang state and its like SEGV occurred from the debug statement.

Please find the following error statements which i have received at that time.

**at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_thread_force_interruption_checkpoint () <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void_*this*_ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_marshal_set_last_error () <0xffffffff>**

Does any one have idea about how to solve this issue or anyone has faced this type of issue in mono?

Comment: Please let me know if anyone has idea about this issue.

Comment: Does any one has idea about how to solve this issue or does any one has faced this type of issue? Please let me know as quickly as possible if any one knows answer about this issue.